# Does React re render the state value and any variables which depend on the state when it is changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I'm a newbie to ReactJS . Is it right when I say : React automatically re render the state value and all of variables which depend on state to determine its data ? .
For instance in this case, Does `let star` variable gets updated by React when `contact.isFavorite` is changed by using `setContact()` ?

```
function App() {
  const [contact, setContact] = useState({
    name: 'Zoe',
    age: 20,
    isFavorite: true,
  });

  let star = contact.isFavorite ? 'star.png' : 'star-unfilled.png';

  function Change() {
    setContact(prevState => ({ ...prevState, isFavorite: !prevState.isFavorite }));
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{contact.name}</p>
      <p>{contact.age}</p>
      <img onClick={Change} src={`./img/${star}`} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: yes, when a state gets new value, all dependencies will recive new value, for your case : if isFavorite get false, star will get  star-unfilled.png

Answer (score 0):

React does re-render your component, but no the state, your state remain (only if your component is not render first time)

in your case variable start will be change value when u click on image